Optimize a C++ Multithreaded Program for Processing Large POSTFIX .tar Files
The program processes files within a large POSTFIX .tar archive using a multithreaded approach, where a worker pool processes files in parallel. It maps the .tar file into memory, distributes the file processing tasks to multiple worker threads using a thread-safe queue, and updates the total count of processed files and their cumulative size. The program measures the time taken to process the tar file and prints it at the end.
Here’s the code I’ve implemented:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>  

// Global atomic variables for counting files and their total size
std::atomic<int> totalFiles(0);
std::atomic<unsigned long> totalSize(0);

// Helper function to convert octal string to integer
unsigned long octalToDec(const std::string& octStr) {
    unsigned long result = 0;
    std::stringstream ss(octStr);
    ss >> std::oct >> result;
    return result;
}

// Simulate processing a file
void processFile(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long fileSize) {
    std::cout << "Processing file: " << fileName << ", size: " << fileSize << " bytes" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));  // Simulate processing

    // Update total files and total size
    totalFiles.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    totalSize.fetch_add(fileSize, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

// Thread-safe queue to manage file processing jobs using mutex
class FileQueue {
public:
    void push(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long fileSize) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        fileQueue_.emplace(fileName, fileSize);
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

    bool pop(std::string& fileName, unsigned long& fileSize) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(lock, [this] { return !fileQueue_.empty() || stop_; });
        if (fileQueue_.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        auto job = fileQueue_.front();
        fileQueue_.pop();
        fileName = job.first;
        fileSize = job.second;
        return true;
    }

    void stop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        stop_ = true;
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::queue<std::pair<std::string, unsigned long>> fileQueue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    bool stop_ = false;
};

// Worker function to process files in parallel
void worker(FileQueue& queue) {
    std::string fileName;
    unsigned long fileSize;
    while (queue.pop(fileName, fileSize)) {
        processFile(fileName, fileSize);
    }
}

// Function to process the postfix tar file and distribute tasks to workers
void processPostfixTarFile(const std::string& tarFilePath, int numWorkers) {
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(
        tarFilePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << tarFilePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;
    if (!GetFileSizeEx(fileHandle, &fileSize)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get file size" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return;
    }

    size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(fileSize.QuadPart);

    HANDLE mappingHandle = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (mappingHandle == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create file mapping" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return;
    }

    char* data = static_cast<char*>(MapViewOfFile(mappingHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));
    if (data == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to map view of file" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(mappingHandle);
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return;
    }

    FileQueue queue;

    // Create a pool of worker threads
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    workers.reserve(numWorkers);  // Pre-allocate memory for worker threads
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; ++i) {
        workers.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(queue));
    }

    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t chunkSize = 512;  // Tar header size is 512 bytes
    const size_t blockSize = 4096;  // Increase block size to speed up processing

    // Iterate through the file, processing tar entries
    while (offset < size) {
        const char* header = &data[offset];

        std::string fileName(header, 100);
        if (fileName.empty()) {
            break;  // End of tar stream
        }

        // Extract file size (from octal string at position 124-135)
        std::string fileSizeStr(header + 124, 11);
        unsigned long fileSize = octalToDec(fileSizeStr);

        // If file size is 0, skip to the next header
        if (fileSize == 0) {
            offset += chunkSize;
            continue;
        }

        // Add file to the queue for processing
        queue.push(fileName, fileSize);

        // Calculate padding, but only perform the operation when necessary
        size_t padding = (fileSize % 512 == 0) ? 0 : 512 - (fileSize % 512);
        offset += chunkSize + fileSize + padding;
    }

    // Stop the workers when all files are processed
    queue.stop();

    // Join all worker threads
    for (auto& workerThread : workers) {
        workerThread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "All files have been processed." << std::endl;

    // Print the total number of files and total size
    std::cout << "Total files found: " << totalFiles.load() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total size: " << totalSize.load() << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // Clean-up
    UnmapViewOfFile(data);
    CloseHandle(mappingHandle);
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
}

int main() {
    std::string tarFilePath = "data\\data (5).tar";  // 17980000 bytes (POSTFIX format) tar file (6600 files, 8.67 seconds)
    int numWorkers = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();  // Automatically use the number of hardware threads

    // Start timing
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    processPostfixTarFile(tarFilePath, numWorkers);

    // End timing
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;

    // Print the elapsed time in seconds
    std::cout << "Time taken to process the tar file: " << duration.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}



Create a struct to hold file information
Even though it's just the file's name and size, I recommend you create a struct to hold these pieces of information together. That will simplify some other things in the code.
struct FileInfo {
    std::string name;
    std::size_t size;
};

void processFile(const FileInfo& fileInfo) {…}

class FileQueue {
    …
    std::queue<FileInfo> fileQueue_;
    …
};

Let pop() return a std::optional
Try to avoid having to pass return values as function parameters. I see why you did this for pop(), as you are returning three pieces of information. However, you can create a single type that combines all that information. Already I showed you struct FileInfo for grouping the file information together. You can use std::optional<FileInfo> to convey that the result may or may not contain file information. Your code will then look like:
class FileQueue {
    …
    std::optional<FileInfo> pop() {
        …
        if (fileQueue_.empty()) {
            return {};
        }
        auto fileInfo = fileQueue.front();
        fileQueue_.pop();
        return fileInfo;
    }
    …
};

void worker(FileQueue& queue) {
    while (auto fileInfo = queue.pop()) {
        processFile(*fileInfo);
    }
}

Use std::jthread
Instead of std::thread, use std::jthread if possible, as it will join threads on destruction automatically.
Notify without holding the mutex
If you call notify_one() or notify_all() on a condition variable, and you are still holding the corresponding the mutex, there is a chance that waiting threads will wake up, see that that mutex is still locked, and then have to immediately sleep again waiting for the mutex to unlock. This is inefficient. You can avoid it by releasing the lock before notifying the threads, for example like so:
void push(const FileInfo& fileInfo) {
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
        fileQueue_.emplace(fileInfo);
    }
    cv_.notify_one();
}

Consider using standard file I/O
You are mapping the tar file into memory using Windows-specific functions. This has several drawbacks. First, your code is no longer portable to other operating systems. Second, very large files might not fit into the address space (although this is rarely a problem on 64-bit machines). Third, while memory mapping can sometimes be efficient, it does rely on page faults to work, which are expensive. Just reading chunks of a few kilobytes into a fixed buffer at a time might actually be more efficient. Finally, suppose an exception is thrown somewhere in processPostfixTarFile(), the file and mapping handles are not automatically cleaned up.
If you are just linearly reading data from the tar file, then using a std::ifstream might be even simpler than doing the memory mapping. The only issue with std::ifstream is that while the operations on them are thread-safe, your threads would each want to seek to different positions in the file, which of course creates a problem. It can be solved by letting every worker open the file themselves.
Use '\n' instead of std::endl
Prefer using '\n' instead of std::endl; the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and might impact performance.
Make the code more generic
The thread-safe queue and thread pool are simple and correct. They are very useful tools in multi-threaded programs. However, you have hardcoded them specifically for processing the tar file. You can easily make the code more generic though, so they can be used for other purposes as well. Consider:
template<typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue {
public:
    void push(const T& item) {…}
    std::optional<T> pop() {…}
    void stop() {…}
private:
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    …
};

void processPostFixTarFile(…) {
    …
    ThreadSafeQueue<FileInfo> queue;
    …
}

You can also make a class ThreadPool to manage worker threads for you, simplifying processPostfixTarFile() itself. Similarly, if you do want to map files into memory, create a class that manages that for you.

I’m not going to do a full review of the code, and in particular, I’m not even going to touch the Windows-specific stuff, because I don’t know anything about Windows. I’ll just focus on some of the generic C++ stuff.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>  

It is generally a good idea to order your headers in a logical way. The reason why is because including headers in a different order can have different effects. If you have #include <iostream> then #include <fstream> in one file, but #include <fstream> then #include <iostream> in another, it becomes difficult, if not impossible, to take advantage of caching and other tricks to speed up compilation.
A good strategy is to group includes by library, and then order them alphabetically.
// Helper function to convert octal string to integer
unsigned long octalToDec(const std::string& octStr) {
    unsigned long result = 0;
    std::stringstream ss(octStr);
    ss >> std::oct >> result;
    return result;
}

This function is not only wildly inefficient, it may also behave differently on different systems, in weird and unexpected ways.
Let’s put aside the inefficiency for the moment and focus on the unpredictability. The issue here is that IOStream formatting is locale-sensitive. When you construct a stream, it picks up the current global C++ locale automatically. The global C++ locale can be set or changed at any time, thousands or even millions of lines away from where this function is called, and maybe even in a different exe or DLL. And it could be different each time the program is run. A different locale could do anything to this function’s logic; it could make supposedly legal octal strings illegal, or make illegal strings legal. Literally anything goes.
If you really don’t intend for anything to go, then whenever you do any IOStreams formatting, you must always make sure to set the locale to something predictable. In this case, you probably want something like:
auto octalToDec(const std::string& octStr) {
    std::stringstream ss(octStr);
    ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());   // explicitly imbue the C/POSIX locale

    unsigned long result = 0;
    ss >> std::oct >> result;
    return result;
}

This will at least work as expected, but it’s still extremely inefficient.
The first problem is that you’re taking a std::string reference as the input. The problem is: you don’t actually need a std::string. You could very well test a character array (C-string). Or just a part of a std::string (and, in fact, this is actually the case in this code).
What you should be taking is a std::string_view. Where you already have a string, this will cost absolutely nothing… but where you don’t it could spare you an expensive construction.
The next issue is the fact that you’re using IOStreams to do the parsing. IOStreams is extremely powerful, but it is also extremely expensive. There is a much, much more efficient solution: std::from_chars():
constexpr auto octalToDec(std::string_view octStr)
{
    auto const p_begin = octStr.data();
    auto const p_end   = octStr.data() + octStr.size();

    auto result = 0uL;
    auto const [p_next, ec] = std::from_chars(p_begin, p_end, result, 8);

    if (ec != std::errc{})
    {
        // There was an error parsing the number. Handle it or report it somehow.
    }

    if (p_next != p_end)
    {
        // There was something after the number (like "123x"). Handle it or report it somehow.
    }

    return result;
}

Note that we can now make the function constexpr. (Note also that I’ve pointed out where you can/should do some error-checking. The original function does no error-checking, but it should.)
// Simulate processing a file
void processFile(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long fileSize) {
    std::cout << "Processing file: " << fileName << ", size: " << fileSize << " bytes" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));  // Simulate processing

    // Update total files and total size
    totalFiles.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    totalSize.fetch_add(fileSize, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

Once again, you’re taking a std::string reference where you may only need a std::string_view. However, in this case, there may actually be a better option: std::filesystem::path const&. That is the more technically correct choice, especially if you intend to use the standard filesystem library. If you’re not, then, well, string_view may be the better choice.
Now, you use unsigned long for file sizes, and that may be fine on Windows, but the standard filesystem library prefers to use std::uintmax_t for file sizes, so that might be a better choice.
Never use std::endl. It is always wrong. Just use '\n'. In this case, you already have the " bytes" string literal, so you could just as well do " bytes\n".
Or, even better: std::println("Processing file: {}, size: {} bytes", fileName, fileSize);.
// Thread-safe queue to manage file processing jobs using mutex
class FileQueue {
public:
    void push(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long fileSize) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        fileQueue_.emplace(fileName, fileSize);
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

    bool pop(std::string& fileName, unsigned long& fileSize) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(lock, [this] { return !fileQueue_.empty() || stop_; });
        if (fileQueue_.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        auto job = fileQueue_.front();
        fileQueue_.pop();
        fileName = job.first;
        fileSize = job.second;
        return true;
    }

    void stop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        stop_ = true;
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::queue<std::pair<std::string, unsigned long>> fileQueue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    bool stop_ = false;
};

Before we dive into the guts of this class, let’s consider it from a high level perspective. It says it’s a “file queue”, which is fine, and it has push and pop operations, which are perfectly normal for a queue… but… then it has a “stop” function. Huh? What does it mean to “stop” a queue?
If I scan down in the code, I see this:
    FileQueue queue;

    // Create a pool of worker threads
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    // ... [snip] ...

    // Stop the workers when all files are processed
    queue.stop();


“Stop the workers…”… but then “queue.stop()”. Something seems a bit confused there.
Let’s take a step back and think of the big picture. What you want is probably:

a list (queue) of files to process; and
a group (vector) of workers (threads) to do the processing.

When you want processing to stop, you don’t the list (queue)… you stop the workers. Your comment even says so.
So the stop() function in FileQueue makes no sense. What does it even mean to stop a list?
However, there is a concept that your file queue may be lacking. There is currently a paper proposing concurrent queues being looked at for C++26. You can check it out if you’re interested, but the key thing I want to point out is the idea of “open” versus “closed” queues. The idea is that if one or more threads are pushing stuff into the queue… and one or more threads are popping stuff off the queue… if a popper discovers that the queue is empty, how do they know whether to wait for more stuff, or if there is nothing more to come?
The answer is the “open”/“close” mechanism. When a thread tries to pop an item off the queue, there are three possible results:

the queue is not empty—it can be either open or closed, doesn’t matter—so the thread gets an item
the queue is empty and open, so there will/may be more items, and thus the thread should wait; or
the queue is empty and closed, there will be no more items.

So the file queue class should not have a “stop” function… but it should have a “close” function. It’s more or less effectively the same thing as what you are doing… but it is conceptually more logical.
Now let’s dig in to the guts of the class. Let’s start with the data members:
    std::queue<std::pair<std::string, unsigned long>> fileQueue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    bool stop_ = false;

std::queue is mostly useless, but it is especially useless as an implementation detail. That is because std::queue is not actually a queue… it’s just a wrapper around a std::vector or std::deque that cripples the interface to make it look like a queue. There is simply no benefit to that crippled interface. Especially not when it’s not even a public interface, but merely an implementation detail. So you might as well just use a std::vector or std::deque directly. For a queue, you’d probably want a std::deque.
    void push(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long fileSize) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        fileQueue_.emplace(fileName, fileSize);
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

So, first, you take the file name as a std::string const&, but then emplace it into the internal queue. That requires making a copy, even when it’s not necessary. But… why? Why not just take the string by value, and then move it into the queue. That gives the caller the option to copy or move.
Also, you are notifying the condition variable while still holding a lock on the mutex. What that will mean is that if any other threads are waiting, they will be notified… and then immediately find themselves blocked because they can’t get a lock on the mutex, so they will have to go back to sleep until the pushing thread finally unlocks the mutex, and then only later wake up again and then do their business. To avoid all that, you should release the lock on the mutex before notifying.
One more important note: you don’t check whether the queue is closed (or “stopped”).
So:
    void push(std::string fileName, unsigned long fileSize)
    {
        if (is_closed())
            // handle error somehow

        auto lock = std::unique_lock{mutex_};

        fileQueue_.emplace(std::move(fileName), fileSize);

        lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

On to pop():
    bool pop(std::string& fileName, unsigned long& fileSize) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(lock, [this] { return !fileQueue_.empty() || stop_; });
        if (fileQueue_.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        auto job = fileQueue_.front();
        fileQueue_.pop();
        fileName = job.first;
        fileSize = job.second;
        return true;
    }

This is not a great interface. I’m aware that it’s more or less the same interface as std::queue… but as I mentioned, std::queue sucks.
There are two problems with this interface. The first is the “out” parameters. This is an anti-pattern, because it requires extra code:
auto name = std::string{};
auto size = 0uL;
queue.pop(name, size);

// instead of:
auto [name, size] = queue.pop();

Not only that… what if you changed the file size to be a std::uintmax_t? Now there is a problem, because we did auto size = 0uL;, making size an unsigned long. But the second version… just works!
Not only that… we can also easily make the elements of the second version const: auto const [name, size] = queue.pop();. That makes for safer code.
The other problem with the interface is the error return code, which is another anti-pattern, because it is too easy to forget to check.
For a better interface, there are two options. You can just do:
auto pop() -> std::tuple<std::string, unsigned long>;

… and throw if there is an error.
Or you can do:
auto pop() -> std::expected<std::tuple<std::string, unsigned long>, ???>;

… where ??? is some error code type.
// Worker function to process files in parallel
void worker(FileQueue& queue) {
    std::string fileName;
    unsigned long fileSize;
    while (queue.pop(fileName, fileSize)) {
        processFile(fileName, fileSize);
    }
}

There doesn’t seem to be any error checking done here. Indeed, there doesn’t seem to be any way to tell whether a file has been processed at all, successfully or not. I would suggest that the workers should take two parameters, at least conceptually: the list of work to do, and a place to post results.
The easiest way to do that would probably be to use promises and futures. I’ll illustrate the idea, and while I’m at it, add co-operative cancellation support.
So, to start, your task data should include all the information for the task, plus a promise for the results. So:
struct task_data
{
    std::string file_name;
    unsigned long file_size;
    std::promise<void> promise;
};

When you create each task, you should collect the future at the same time:
auto tasks = concurrent_queue<task_data>{};
auto futures = concurrent_queue<std::future<void>>{};

// ...

while (offset < size)
{
    // ...

    // Add file to the queue for processing
    auto task = task_data{std::move(file_name), file_size};

    futures.emplace_back(task.promise.get_future());
    tasks.emplace_back(std::move(task));

    // ...
}

Now let’s look at the worker threads, which should be std::jthreads, not std::threads:
// Create a pool of worker threads
auto workers = std::vector<std::jthread>(num_workers);
std::ranges::generate(workers, [&worker, &queue]() { return std::jthread{worker, std::ref(queue)}; });

And the worker function should take a std::stop_token as its first argument:
auto worker(std::stop_token stop_token, concurrent_queue<task_data>& tasks)
{
    while (not stop_token.stop_requested())
    {
        // Might want a timeout here, so you don't get stuck waiting forever
        // if there are no more tasks, but the task queue hasn't been closed.
        // Or do something like a try-pop, with an else that has the thread
        // yield/sleep.
        if (auto task = tasks.pop(); task)
        {
            // One last chance to bail...
            if (stop_token.stop_requested())
                break;

            try
            {
                // I’ve left processFile() unchanged... but if processing
                // is going to take a while, and can be cancelled mid-way
                // through, then maybe it should also take a stop_token
                // argument, so we can pass the stop token.
                processFile(task->file_name, task->file_size);
                task->promise.set_value();
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                task->promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
        }
    }
}

So now, what you want to do is catch any unexpected errors, and cancel any unfinished tasks:
// Create a pool of worker threads
// ...

try
{
    // ... the big loop that processes the tar file and creates the tasks...
}
catch (...)
{
    std::ranges::for_each(workers, [](auto&& worker) { worker.request_stop(); });

    throw;
}

And after it all, wait for the promises to deliver. Put altogether (very roughly, of course):
auto worker(std::stop_token stop_token, concurrent_queue<task_data>& tasks)
{
    while (not stop_token.stop_requested())
    {
        auto ec = conqueue_errc{};
        if (auto task = tasks.try_pop(ec); task)
        {
            if (stop_token.stop_requested())
                break;

            try
            {
                processFile(task->file_name, task->file_size);
                task->promise.set_value();
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                task->promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
        }
        else if (ec == conqueue_errc::closed)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
}

auto processPostfixTarFile(std::filesystem::path const& tarFilePath, int numWorkers)
{
    auto file_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    auto mapping_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    auto data = static_cast<char*>(nullptr);
    // ... open the file, etc. ...

    try
    {
        auto tasks = concurrent_queue<task_data>{};
        auto futures = concurrent_queue<std::future<void>>{};

        auto workers = std::vector<std::jthread>(num_workers);
        std::ranges::generate(workers, [&worker, &queue]() { return std::jthread{worker, std::ref(queue)}; });

        try
        {
            // ... the big-ass loop...
            while (offset < size)
            {
                // ...

                // Add file to the queue for processing
                auto task = task_data{std::move(file_name), file_size};

                futures.emplace_back(task.promise.get_future());
                tasks.emplace_back(std::move(task));

                // ...
            }

            tasks.close();
            futures.close();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::ranges::for_each(workers, [](auto&& worker) { worker.request_stop(); });

            throw;
        }

        // At this point, we've queued all the tasks, and they're all being
        // handled (or possibly already done). So.. we just wait for them.
        // If any have failed, they will throw.
        for (auto&& task_result : futures)
            task_result.get();

        std::cout << "All files have been processed.\n";

        // Print the total number of files and total size
        std::cout << "Total files found: " << totalFiles.load() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Total size: " << totalSize.load() << " bytes\n";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        if (data)
            ::UnmapViewOfFile(data);
        if (mapping_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ::CloseHandle(mapping_handle);
        if (file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ::CloseHandle(file_handle);

        throw;
    }

    ::UnmapViewOfFile(data);
    ::CloseHandle(mapping_handle);
    ::CloseHandle(file_handle);
}

That gives you co-operative cancellation, and the ability to know if all the tasks actually succeeded before reporting it to be so.
Okay, let’s get back to the code, still looking at processPostfixTarFile(). A massive chunk of this function deals with opening the file, mapping the file, and so on… all of which has nothing specifically to do with processing tar files.
On top of that, the function is very exception-unsafe. You do a little bit of C-style error handling at the top of the function… but once you start making the actual work queue and the worker threads, you forget all about that. Anything there might throw, and then all those handles will never be closed.
What you really need to do is pull all that junk out, and make it a type:
class mapped_file
{
public:
    explicit mapped_file(std::filesystem::path const& path)
    {
        try
        {
            _file = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if (_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                throw std::runtime_error{"failed to open file: " + path.string()};

            auto size = LARGE_INTEGER{};
            if (not ::GetFileSizeEx(_file, &size))
                throw std::runtime_error{"failed to get file size: " + path.string()};

            _size = static_cast<std::size_t>(size.QuadPart);

            _mapping = ::CreateFileMapping(_file, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
            if (_mapping == NULL)
                throw std::runtime_error{"failed to create file mapping: " + path.string()};

            _data = static_cast<char*>(::MapViewOfFile(_mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));
            if (_data == NULL)
                throw std::runtime_error{"failed to map view of file: " + path.string()}
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            if (_data)
                ::UnmapViewOfFile(_data);
            if (_mapping != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                ::CloseHandle(_mapping);
            if (_file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                ::CloseHandle(_file);

            throw;
        }
    }

    mapped_file(mapped_file&& other) noexcept
    {
        std::ranges::swap(*this, other);
    }

    ~mapped_file()
    {
        if (_data)
            ::UnmapViewOfFile(_data);
        if (_mapping != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ::CloseHandle(_mapping);
        if (_file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ::CloseHandle(_file);
    }

    auto data()       noexcept { return _data; }
    auto data() const noexcept { return static_cast<char const*>(_data); }

    auto size() const noexcept { return _size; }

    auto operator=(mapped_file&& other) noexcept -> mapped_file&
    {
        std::ranges::swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    friend auto swap(mapped_file& a, mapped_file& b) noexcept
    {
        std::ranges::swap(a._file, b._file);
        std::ranges::swap(a._mapping, b._mapping);
        std::ranges::swap(a._size, b._size);
        std::ranges::swap(a._data, b._data);
    }

    mapped_file(mapped_file const&) = delete;
    auto operator=(mapped_file const&) -> mapped_file& = delete;

private:
    HANDLE      _file    = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE      _mapping = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    std::size_t _size    = {};
    char*       _data    = {};
};

And now processPostfixTarFile() goes from this (which is broken):
void processPostfixTarFile(const std::string& tarFilePath, int numWorkers) {
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(
        tarFilePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << tarFilePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;
    if (!GetFileSizeEx(fileHandle, &fileSize)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get file size" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return;
    }

    size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(fileSize.QuadPart);

    HANDLE mappingHandle = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (mappingHandle == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create file mapping" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return;
    }

    char* data = static_cast<char*>(MapViewOfFile(mappingHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));
    if (data == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to map view of file" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(mappingHandle);
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return;
    }

    FileQueue queue;

    // Create a pool of worker threads
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    workers.reserve(numWorkers);  // Pre-allocate memory for worker threads
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; ++i) {
        workers.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(queue));
    }

    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t chunkSize = 512;  // Tar header size is 512 bytes
    const size_t blockSize = 4096;  // Increase block size to speed up processing

    // Iterate through the file, processing tar entries
    while (offset < size) {
        const char* header = &data[offset];

        std::string fileName(header, 100);
        if (fileName.empty()) {
            break;  // End of tar stream
        }

        // Extract file size (from octal string at position 124-135)
        std::string fileSizeStr(header + 124, 11);
        unsigned long fileSize = octalToDec(fileSizeStr);

        // If file size is 0, skip to the next header
        if (fileSize == 0) {
            offset += chunkSize;
            continue;
        }

        // Add file to the queue for processing
        queue.push(fileName, fileSize);

        // Calculate padding, but only perform the operation when necessary
        size_t padding = (fileSize % 512 == 0) ? 0 : 512 - (fileSize % 512);
        offset += chunkSize + fileSize + padding;
    }

    // Stop the workers when all files are processed
    queue.stop();

    // Join all worker threads
    for (auto& workerThread : workers) {
        workerThread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "All files have been processed." << std::endl;

    // Print the total number of files and total size
    std::cout << "Total files found: " << totalFiles.load() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total size: " << totalSize.load() << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // Clean-up
    UnmapViewOfFile(data);
    CloseHandle(mappingHandle);
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
}

… to this (which is mostly exception-safe⁕):
void processPostfixTarFile(const std::string& tarFilePath, int numWorkers) {
    auto const data = mapped_file{tarFilePath};

    FileQueue queue;

    // Create a pool of worker threads
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    workers.reserve(numWorkers);  // Pre-allocate memory for worker threads
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; ++i) {
        workers.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(queue));
    }

    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t chunkSize = 512;  // Tar header size is 512 bytes
    const size_t blockSize = 4096;  // Increase block size to speed up processing

    // Iterate through the file, processing tar entries
    while (offset < data.size()) {
        const char* header = data.data() + offset;

        std::string fileName(header, 100);
        if (fileName.empty()) {
            break;  // End of tar stream
        }

        // Extract file size (from octal string at position 124-135)
        std::string fileSizeStr(header + 124, 11);
        unsigned long fileSize = octalToDec(fileSizeStr);

        // If file size is 0, skip to the next header
        if (fileSize == 0) {
            offset += chunkSize;
            continue;
        }

        // Add file to the queue for processing
        queue.push(fileName, fileSize);

        // Calculate padding, but only perform the operation when necessary
        size_t padding = (fileSize % 512 == 0) ? 0 : 512 - (fileSize % 512);
        offset += chunkSize + fileSize + padding;
    }

    // Stop the workers when all files are processed
    queue.stop();

    // Join all worker threads
    for (auto& workerThread : workers) {
        workerThread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "All files have been processed." << std::endl;

    // Print the total number of files and total size
    std::cout << "Total files found: " << totalFiles.load() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total size: " << totalSize.load() << " bytes" << std::endl;
}

⁕ (It’s not exception-safe yet, partly because it uses std::thread and not std::jthread, and partly because there is no mechanism to prevent the worker threads from blocking indefinitely.)
In other words, the entire function is now all stuff actually relevant to processing a tar file, rather than opening and mapping files in general.
Incidentally, it’s std::size, not just size_t. The latter “works” due to historical reasons, but there’s a good chance that will not be true in the near future.
Finally, main():
    int numWorkers = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();  // Automatically use the number of hardware threads

std::thread::hardware_concurrency() may return zero.
    return 0;

This is unnecessary.
However, do bear in mind that your program is not exception safe. If anything throws, main() will just terminate and print whatever diagnostic your compiler/library wants.
Generally, you want to do something like:
auto main() -> int
{
    try
    {
        // everything that is currently in main()'s body
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return handle_error();
    }
}

… where handle_error() is a Lippincott function:
auto handle_error()
{
    try
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& x)
    {
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]: " << x.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]: unknown error\n";
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

That’s it. Hope it helps!
